# Time measurements in R

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to measure time used to solve a sysitem in R:

```
t1<-Sys.time()
b=t(Q)%*%t(Pi)%*%z
Sol<-BackwardSubs(R,b)
t2<-Sys.time()
DeltaT<-t2-t1
print(paste("System: ",DeltaT," sec",sep=""))
```

Sometimes i find results (1 or 2 seconds when the function execution is several minutes) with high dimensions of the problem that are not possible.

Is `Sys.time()` correct?

Comment: Use the package [`microbenchmark`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html) for accurate results.

Comment: Also consider using `system.time()`.

Comment: Please consider adding the necessary objects (`Q`,`Pi`,`z`,`BackwardSubs`,`R`, and `b`) for others to reproduce your question and test it properly.

Comment: Sounds like the algorithm is quickly throwing an error and exiting.

Comment: Code works with `proc.time()` or `system.time()` so i changed the command